# Salesforce Lightning Case Assign to Me button

Tags: lightning, custom-button, quickaction

In Salesforce Lightning I am trying to make a button on the case layout which assigns a case to the user viewing it. I want this button to be a single click and the case owner is reassigned and the page is refreshed to show the new owner. There are a lot of examples of this working with JavaScript in Salesforce classic but Salesforce Lightning does not support JavaScript buttons on layouts so I can not figure out how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a button that starts a flow, the flow can reassign the case and you can use a lightning web component on a flow screen with some javascript to refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an "update a record" action. Set the predefined value of Owner field to current user and remove all fields from layout.

This will allow you to have a 2 clicks update.

If you really want one click, you will need to make a [headless quick action](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/use_quick_actions_headless). This involves some development whereas the other method only use point&click.

Comment: Can't set Owner in a predefined field value. Unfortunately.